# Мой код на Python почему-то не работает

Tags: python

Мой код на Python почему-то не работает. Пишет ошибку на второй строке. Объясните пожалуйста почему?

```
Russ_sum["а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я"]
Code_sum["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a+","b+","c+"."d+","e+","f+","g+"]
a [] = str(input())
for(i=0, i++, i= 33 )
    j=0
    if a[i] == Russ_sum[j]:
        a.list.insert(i, Russ_sum[j])
        print(Russ_sum[j])
    else:
        j++
```

Comment: проблема в точке: `"c+".`

Comment: Ну вы бы текст ошибки почитали))) По опыту скажу, что помогает)))

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. А вы не знаете, как сделать динамический список или массив? Просто мне нужно, чтобы список заполнялся вводом

Comment: @Desertdevelober https://devpractice.ru/python-lessons/ вот вам полезный ресурс (в pdf бесплатно скачивается) ознакомьтесь с типами данных. Книга не большая, но понятно и просто расписаны типы и методы работы с ними

Comment: Спасибо вам за ресурс. Обязательно воспользуюсь

Comment: Это вообще не похоже на код на Python

Answer (score 0):

Это не код на Питон, вы вероятно работаете в C/C++/Java/PHP, ...

На Питоне всё более просто. Вы наверно хотели:

```
Russ_sum = ("а","б","в","г","д","е","ё","ж","з","и","й","к","л","м","н","о","п","р","с","т","у","ф","х","ц","ч","ш","щ","ъ","ы","ь","э","ю","я")
Code_sum = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a+","b+","c+","d+","e+","f+","g+")

a = input()
b = []

for i in a:                 # не надо индексов - i просто текущий символ из а
    j = Russ_sum.index(i)   # индекс текущего символа в таблице Russ_sum
    b.append(Code_sum[j])

result = "".join(b)         # строка из списка
print(result)
```

Пример ввода:

```
собака
```

Вывод:

```
spbala
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, я просто с С++ перехожу на питон, а потому вот так выходит

Comment: @Desertdevelober, не стоит. Вы можете пометить мой ответ как принятым и/или дать ему голос.